# iPhone Developer handle

Tags: iphone

So I just starting coding iPhone apps, and a potential employer had asked what me, "What is your Developer Handle?"  What exactly did he mean by "Developer Handle"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely what name your apps are listed under in the iTunes store. This can be your company name or your own name, depending on how you apply.

Comment: I'll second @John. When you setup your iOS Developer Profile it will ask for your name and optional company name. Please accept the response by @John if you are happy with it.